# C# Application Restart does not call program Main()

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I've already wrote an application that works user base. I was looking for the best way to use for current user logging-out. So I've used   `Application.Restart();` 
Soon I found that the code doesn't work properly and `Program.Main()` doesn't call back again.
I wondered that my  ***Login form Load Method*** is not going to perform (The Login Form is calling from program class).

So I'll really thankful if you let me know about my bugs and correct solutions.

Comment: How do you know Main isn't being called again?

Comment: @jglouie I've used breakpoint in it

Comment: You'd probably need to attach to the new process that gets spawned

Comment: On multithreaded apps, break points only work on the main thread afaik

Comment: @ColeJohnson You can set breakpoints in other threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx

**Comment listed "Bug in VS2010 SP1"**

> after calling this method, the application no longer run in debug mode, it's not spawned by the IDE and all breakpoints stop functioning.

*EDIT:*
This is where something like log4net can really be helpful. It's a very simple library to add to your project and would let you write out debug information to a file so, even though the next instance wasn't spawned by the IDE and wont get breakpoints, you could still do some verification that it's hitting what you expect through the use of Debug traces. Just a suggestion...

Comment: Very Helpful . . . As you told, Debug mode was main problem . . . thank u

Answer (score 2):

A new process gets created, and it's not spawned by the IDE.

A breakpoint is not a valid way to test if `Main` is entered again.

See somewhat related post:
[Does Application.Restart() creates new process for application or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530722/does-application-restart-creates-new-process-for-application-or-no)

If you'd like, you could write to a file or some other simple test in `Main` just to prove to yourself that it is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently released a solution that allows debugging to continue after `Application.Restart()`, in the form of a Power Tool:

## Child Process Debugging Power Tool

- [Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx)
- [Download in VS Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1141bff-463f-465f-9b6d-d29b7b503d7a)